How to Ground a Photodiode and TIA combination
I have a TIA circuit as below, In simple terms the Photo diode is a APD C30955EH and Circuit is supposed to work up to 100Khz signals digitalization.

The supply which is powering the circuit is a noisy one which would affect the performance of the circuit, so i have chosen to keep the TIA circuit ground to be separate called AGND
Now the photo diode is connected to this circuit by photo conductive mode, where a high voltage is given to photo diode and its reverse biased, the anode is connected to input of above circuit
what is the best way to connect the photo diode case ground here ?
should the photo diode case ground should be connected to silent AGND or PGND of High voltage supply?
How to deal with Ground in case of high sensitive TIA and Photodiode configurations

Your circuit doesn't have the photodiode reverse biased, so I'm a little confused by your description. But assuming that is a mistake, since the high voltage supply sources the current that returns to AGND, there is little point in treating the grounds separately as they are ultimately connected.

@user1850479 Photodiodes work at zero bias, just not as fast or sensitively as when biased.

@user1850479 updated picture

@JohnDoty did not get your point, photo diodes can go up to Ghz of pulse usage, typically used in communication in band of 1550nm coupled with optical fiber, but that discussion is not relevant here, i am only concerned about how to deal with case ground of photo diode package and how to connect them power supply ground, on argument is they are to be isolated from noisy high voltage other point it, its better to grounded with PGND

Since your high voltage supply is providing current to the op amps, AGND and PGND have to be connected.  As drawn if AGND is different than PGND then the APD is not reverse biased because the HV supply would be floating.
As for the case terminal, it is just the case ground of the device, so you would tie it to whatever ground the rest of the system uses.
If noise from the HV supply is a problem, add filtering.  The datasheet specs a max reverse current in microamps, so for safety purposes you probably want to have a large current limiting resistor regardless.  Add a capacitor and you have an RC filter.

HVCC is having a different PGND, the + and - 5V is also having same PGND, i seperated the alone Opamp section to have AGND to keep it away from noisy PGND

@kakeh Your schematic shows everything referenced to AGND, which is what you need to do.  If you try to separate GNDs then your circuit won't work.

i updated the scheme, i have a seperate PSU card which delivers HVCC, PGND, V5+ and V5- to this board

It looks to me like you're saying that you connected both grounds together, which is correct.

The RC filter ground should refer to pgnd or agnd ?

Since they're connected everything will reference both. Physically I would put the filter in the high voltage power supply if possible.

@kakeh You say PGND is noisy. Noisy relative to what reference potential? Why have a reference potential other than PGND?

PGND is from HV DCDC , i feel i should put a input CLC filter while bringing it to current PCB from outside from a different module
